# output of array is different from input

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to input

```
1
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

but for some reason im getting this as my output 
`HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIHHH`

It should output the same exact thing all the H but its not its outputting less and a random I. What is that?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int arrayElements = 40;
int main()
{
    int lineInputs = 0;

    cin >> lineInputs;

    char mySexyArray [lineInputs-1][arrayElements-1];
    int whatever =0;
    for (int i=0;i<lineInputs;i++)
    {
       // cin >> whatever;
        for (int j=0;j<arrayElements;j++)
        {
           cin >>mySexyArray[i][j];
        }
    }




    for (int i=0;i<lineInputs;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<arrayElements;j++)
        {
          cout << mySexyArray[i][j]<<"";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you input `1` for `lineInputs`, what is the value of `lineInputs-1`?

Comment: How is it possible to declare char mySexyArray [lineInputs][arrayElements] when lineInputs isn't constant, it should give an error

Comment: @StackHeapCollision: That's understandable most compilers support variable length arrays through extensions and not everyone compiles there code with `-pedantic`, which they ideally should.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector<std::string>` rather than a C-style array? It would make your code much neater and less prone to off-by-one errors and buffer over-runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the bounds of the array resulting in **Undefined Behavior**.
When you have an program with Undefined behavior, it can show you any output.

Your array declaration is:

```
char mySexyArray [lineInputs-1][arrayElements-1];
```

While your loop runs:

```
 for (int i=0;i<lineInputs;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<arrayElements;j++)
```

Array subscripts begin from `0` so just wrote to an memory that does not belong to your array.